# How to get rid of not existing errors?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my code

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from .models import Actor
from .serializers import ActorSerializer

# Create your views here.

class ActorView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Actor
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ActorSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = ActorSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ActorSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            print(serializer.validated_data['name'])
            return Response("OK", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else: 
            return Response("nie ok")
```

Pylance thinks that this line:

```
print(serializer.validated_data['name'])
```

is incorrect, but it is correct. Code works fine and it doesn't displaying any errors while server is running and request is sent. But it is underlined in red, so something must be wrong. How can i get rid of those "errors"?

```
"__getitem__" method not defined on type "empty"
Object of type "None" is not subscriptable
```

I have alredy tried uninstalling Pylance and changing its' version but all for nothing.

Comment: Of course there is.  These static analyzers are basically using AI to reconstruct your program's actions.  They don't always understand every nuance in a dynamic language.  If you have double-checked things, then don't worry about it.

Comment: There should be an error code with that message. Once you've analyzed the code and determined it is actually correct, you can add `#noqa <code>` at the end of the line and static analysis should stop reporting it. That works with mypy and pylint, but I don't know if it also works with pylance.

Comment: If you `print(serializer.validated_data)`, are there cases where it shows `None`?

Comment: @TimRoberts No, it is showing the value of name, i.e if I send request {"name": "example"}, it will print "example". I have no idea why Pylance thinks it is incorrect.

Comment: `validated_data` is a variable that is filled during the call to `is_valid`, if the data is not valid `validated_data` most likely is `None`, PyLance does some Static Type Analysis but not runtime, it does not see that you access it after a True test of `is_valid` and that means that `validated_data` is filled

Comment: what does the tooltip say when you hover over `validated_data`, what type does PyLance think it is

Comment: This is not a problem with VS Code, but within your models. Do you mind posting your models?